# How i can order the jitter-points on a Boxplot in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

My data (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cdpVNzw63OaJamvA272WefoTyXIVjaU9/view?usp=drive_link) are essentially measures of growth of jellyfishes, they are categorized by treatment (3 different temperature of incubation) by Replicates and by time (Week and day from the beginning).

I want to visualize the data in the form of boxplot. In particular, for every week I want to visualize the data by treatment (or vice versa) with the associated points but geom_jitter doesn't put in order the points

This is what I've done now:

```
b<- sanderia %>%
  ggplot( aes(x=Week, y=Growth, fill=Treat )) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE, alpha=0.6) +
    geom_jitter( aes(color=Rep, fill=Treat), size=0.4, alpha=0.9) +
    theme_ipsum() +
    theme(
      plot.title = element_text(size=11)
    ) +
    ggtitle("A boxplot with jitter") +
    xlab("")
```

[image: the output graphic I obtained]

I tried to put in the aes() of geom_jitter the fill, and the group but nothing seems to work...

I would like to somehow order the points by Week so they will fall in their box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to *dodge* the points according to their `Week`, but also *jitter* them for clarity around their association boxplot. To do this, use `geom_point`, with `Week` as a grouping variable, and use `position = position_jitterdodge()`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(sanderia, aes(x = Treat, y = Growth, fill = factor(Week))) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.colour = NA) +
  scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE, alpha = 0.6) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Rep, group = factor(Week)), 
             size = 0.8, alpha = 0.5, 
             position = position_jitterdodge(0.25, 0, 0.75)) +
  hrbrthemes::theme_ipsum() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 11)) +
  labs(x = NULL, fill = 'Week', title = "A boxplot with jitter")
```

[image]